# How does Oracle 10g use indexes?

Tags: oracle, oracle-10g

I have table called `result`:

```
CREATE TABLE result
    (id_graduate                    NUMBER NOT NULL,
    id_sml                         NUMBER NOT NULL,
    last_update                    DATE NOT NULL,
    id_kt                          NUMBER NOT NULL,
    value_kt                       NUMBER NOT NULL,
    id_res                         NUMBER NOT NULL)
/
ALTER TABLE result
ADD CONSTRAINT pk_id_res PRIMARY KEY (id_res)
```

And an index:

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX x_pk_id_res ON result
  (
    id_res                          ASC
  )
  STORAGE   (
    INITIAL     65536
    MINEXTENTS  1
    MAXEXTENTS  2147483645
  )
NOPARALLEL
LOGGING
/
```

When I run SQL query #1, Oracle uses index `X_PK_ID_RES`

```
select ss.*
from V_JOURNAL ss, result r
where TO_NUMBER(ss.ID_SML||ss.ID_KT||ss.ID_GRADUATE)=r.id_res
```

But, when I run SQL query #2, Oracle does not use index `X_PK_ID_RES`. Instead it uses an `ACCESS FULL TABLE` access path.

```
select ss.*,r.* 
from V_JOURNAL ss, result r
where TO_NUMBER(ss.ID_SML||ss.ID_KT||ss.ID_GRADUATE)=r.id_res
```

So, I added a new column `id_res2`:

```
ALTER TABLE RESULT  ADD (  ID_RES2 NUMBER );
```

And I created a new index:

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX x_id_res2 ON result
  (
    id_res2                          ASC
  )
  STORAGE   (
    INITIAL     65536
    MINEXTENTS  1
    MAXEXTENTS  2147483645
  )
NOPARALLEL
LOGGING
```

When I run SQL query #3, Oracle uses index `X_ID_RES2`.

```
select ss.* 
from V_JOURNAL ss, result r
where TO_NUMBER(ss.ID_SML||ss.ID_KT||ss.ID_GRADUATE)=r.id_res2
```

And, when I run SQL query #4, Oracle uses index `X_ID_RES2` too.

```
select ss.*,r.* 
from V_JOURNAL ss, result r
where TO_NUMBER(ss.ID_SML||ss.ID_KT||ss.ID_GRADUATE)=r.id_res2
```

Why did Oracle use an index in SQL #4, but did not use one in SQL #2?

Comment: [Cross-posted on SO](http://stackoverflow.com/q/21380789/266304).

Comment: Unless I'm missing something, there was no index to use for query2. You created it after?! Why didn't you just create an index on `result.id_res` ? You may be better off creating a functional index on `TO_NUMBER(ss.ID_SML||ss.ID_KT||ss.ID_GRADUATE)`

Comment: @Phil - query 2 is against `id_res`, not `id_res2`... but  it's not clear if it has the PK or UI against it (since they can't both be there against the same column as written). I mentioned on the SO version that it might have switched from a full index scan to a full table scan because it's selecting `r.*` in query 2; but awaiting the execution plans to see why query 4 didn't do the same... I'm guessing stats, or because `id_res2` is nullable. Maybe.

Comment: Oh, I should read more carefully. *Slaps self*

Comment: Did you gather statistics for the table and the indexes before you ran your query?  On Oracle 10g, you may not have up to date complete statistics on the newly-created indexes immediately.

`exec dbms_stats.gather_table_stats(user, 'RESULT', cascade=>true);`

will gather table and index stats.

Comment: How many records do you have in your table?  What's the cardinality like in these fields?  A low-cardinality index may not be useful: it may be faster to just scan a table with 1 M records then to scan an index with 1 M entries, and then seek the full records for 500 K of them.

Answer (score 2):

When Oracle uses an index, it has to lookup the actual data of the table in the table itself. Remember, an index is just a list of pointers to the actual data ordered in some way. The index itself only contains the indexed columns.

So, if you specify

```
select ss.*,r.* 
from V_JOURNAL ss, result r
where TO_NUMBER(ss.ID_SML||ss.ID_KT||ss.ID_GRADUATE)=r.id_res2
```

You are asking for the contents of ALL columns in v_journal and result. Oracle can then choose based on heuristics (rule based) or statistics (nowadays) what is expected to be cheaper. When the number of expected returned rows is high compared to the total size of the tables, a full table scan is considered cheaper (and is often faster, but please remember it may purge your database cache as a nasty side effect).

When you replace it by something just needing the data in the index like:

```
select count(*)
from V_JOURNAL ss, result r
where TO_NUMBER(ss.ID_SML||ss.ID_KT||ss.ID_GRADUATE)=r.id_res2
```

All needed data can be found in the index and the index will be used as a cheap full table scan (full index scan), since the index is probably smaller in size in bytes.